# getting "error Unsupported Media Type" while binding JSON data with spring mvc controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, jstree

I am capturing a hierarchical data using Jquery based Jstree library.Data is in a JSON format, I want to capture and bind this data to my bean class(JstreeJson.java).Here is what I have tried so far..

Ajax call :

```
 function getJSON() {       
              var jstree = $('#jstree1').jstree(true).get_json('#', {flat:true});
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jstree));
              $.ajax({          
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"createObjective",
                    data : { jstree: jstree },                      
                    dataType :"json", 
                    success : function(result) {
                        console.log(jstree);
                    console.log(result);
                 },
                 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     console.log(jqXHR);
                     console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
                 }
            }); 

         }
```

console.log output:

```
[{"id":"j1_1","text":"Simple root node","icon":true,"li_attr":{"id":"j1_1"},"a_attr":{"href":"#","id":"j1_1_anchor"},"state":{"loaded":true,"opened":false,"selected":false,"disabled":false},"data":{},"parent":"#"}]
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createObjective",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String createObjective(@RequestBody JstreeJson jstree)
{
    System.out.println(jstree);
    return "done";
}
```

Bean class

```
public class JstreeJson
{
  private String id;
  private String text;
  private String parent;
   // getters and setter
 }
```

I have tried adding consumes and Headers but it didnt have any effect on my output

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/createObjective",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json",headers = "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

Comment: Use `headers = "Accept=application/json"` on @RequestMapping and remove consumes attribute.

Comment: didn't work getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this @RequestMapping:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createObjective" method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes= {"application/json;charset=UTF-8"}, produces={"application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
public @ResponseBody String createObjective(@RequestBody JstreeJson jstree)
{
    System.out.println(jstree);
    return "done";
}
```

Or you can keep @RequestMapping simple as bellow:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/createObjective")
```

Spring will take care rest of the attributes of @RequestMapping depending on request.

Comment: No change whatsoever still getting "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)"

Comment: added contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" to .ajax and now I'm getting: error Bad Request

Comment: 400 bad request means that your request body is mailformed. Add this annotation on top of you `JsTreeJson` class because i'm seeing property named `icon` in your request body which is not present in your bean. `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` this annotation means that during deserialization will not include unknown properties.

Comment: data : { jstree: jstree }  instead of this can you try   data :jstree   because it's already a json object. And use JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)  as suggested by Nikolay Rusev

Comment: added @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) and changed data as you said but still getting 400:bad request. I think there is a issue with my @Requestmapping or .ajax method attribute. any suggestions Shekhar Nikolay?